# Upgrading iPhone/Xcode broke my cocoapod libraries

Tags: ios, swift2, swift3, xcode7, xcode8

I recently upgraded my iPhone to iOS 10, which then required me to update to Xcode 8, which broke my imported libraries, namely Alamofire and PusherSwift. I was forced to convert my Swift2 code to Swift3, and it then forced me to update the libraries to Swift3, which broke them. Any ideas on what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is suffer through it, I'm afraid.

It is possible to use Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8, but you have to set a build setting to do so, and the fact is that Swift 2 is now out-of-date, and the longer you wait to move to Swift 3, the more painful it's going to be.

Comment: But is there anything I can do about the libraries? I did a pod deintegrate, pod clean, and then pod install hoping they'd fix themselves when they downloaded but that came up fruitless

Comment: If you change your pod files to specify the latest versions then a pod upgrade should upgrade your pods to Swift 3 versions. That was my experience with the couple of swift pod-based frameworks I needed to upgrade to Swift 3.